# issue typing an object react typescript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having issues typing the following:

```
// if I remove the `any` below it breaks.
const teams: any = {
    liverpool: <Liverpool />,
    manUtd: <ManUtd />,
    arsenal: <Arsenal />,
};

export const TeamCrest = ({ team }: { team: keyof typeof teams }) =>
  teams[team];
```

It is the used elsewhere:

```
<TeamCrest team={'liverpool'} />
```

If I do `const teams : any {....}` it works, but without this I get the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '

Can anyone advise how to type this correctly?

Comment: Maybe `export const TeamCrest = ({ team }: { team: keyof typeof teams }) =>    teams[team];`

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type liverpool....

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir updated question, any ideas?

Comment: The solution I and @Karol below suggested works, I tested it: https://typescript-play.js.org/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBlgA3JKSCAGwAoBKOAG84RGJSiMAPAD4pAehlwAvhRp0GcALIpqAVRgATAcNFJxkuLIVLVVWjHqMAglADOSaij6CRYidJyiiqk8vJwwJhwAJJmIBDscDAAFkhwAAa6AJ7pcABGSNwQAO4R8HlEKADWbgB0pGgMbvAwqCBucHAAvMKkndxsHFzcAFxWLOycEDxwigA0fXAgugaGY1I6+kazMgudKO6e3uuuHl7cOwvKANzkSAAekLBwjdTNcAAqbQDCRO89vBErRQeGUYyBbTGVSQWQgURgWTASDhSTaHWUgi6SmB7QA2jiALq3bjmOAdHpSL4g35Id44rpCfADSbDfDKHZAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). The following works:

```
export const teams: Record<string, JSX.Element> = {
 ....
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this would get downvoted. I asked the question and this was the solution :-D the other answer wasn't the issue 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir was what silenced the linter :-D

Answer (score 0):

`team` is not any string, but a very specific one.

```
export const TeamCrest = ({ team }: { team: keyof typeof teams }) =>
  teams[team];
```

Comment: file type is actually passed in as a string. This doesn't resolve the issue. The issue is to do with the object - `const teams`. If I do `const teams : any {....}` it works. Updated the question a bit

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you create a StackBlitz instance to demonstrate the problem?